# Not sure what tool/language will use "curly brace" syntax in asp.net web form page

Tags: asp.net, mustache

I am responsible for maintaining a asp.net web form page(not mvc, not razor), and found some curly brace syntax I am not familiar with.

The following is the example,

```
{{#CurrencyRates}}
<div class="{{^IsLast}}tzsg-padding-bottom-xl tzsg-border-bottom-light{{/IsLast}} tzsg-margin-top-xl"></div>
{{#HasWhatsIncludedRateLevel}}
```

As you can see, those curly brace even shows in css attribute.
I double that it may be angularJS syntax, but can not find any related angularJS files or syntax, like ng-app.

My question is: what tool/language it is.
Thank you.

Updated Status:
Thanks for Arindam Nayak's hint, and I found out it is using mustache.js.

Comment: This is a guess, but that looks like angular js to me

Comment: might be jquery template.

Comment: AngularJS or Handlebars.js ...

Comment: @ArindamNayak , thank you for the hint/key word. I found it is using mustache.js!